# How to add angular attribute directive to input in rails slim template?

Tags: angularjs, html, templates, ruby-on-rails-4, slim-lang

Trying to attach custom angular attribute directive to rails slim template. But all attempts are not successful.

Here is the code

```
input#title.form-control placeholder="Product titile" type="text" ng-model='product.title' server-error
```

where 'server-error' is a custom directive. But when browser renders this html this directive is cutted off and printed as a plain text.

Can you advice something?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using **parenthesis syntax**:

`input#title.form-control(type='text' ng-model='product.title' server-error)`

This should also work:

`input#title.form-control type='text' ng-model='product.title' server-error=''`